# Break out of parent div

Tags: css

I am trying to get the the menu on the right side of the search bar to breakout of the parent.

Code: http://jsbin.com/xecolubodi/edit?html,css,js,output

I believe a modified to the following css styles is required:

```
.mapsearch-menu ul {
    display: none;
    position: relative;
    top: -55px;
    padding: 55px 0 0 0;
    margin: 0;
    user-select: none;
}
.mapsearch-menu ul:hover {
    display: block;
}
.mapsearch-menu li {
    background: white;
    padding: 4px;
    list-style: none;
    border: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.298039);
    margin-top: -1px;
}
.mapsearch-menu input[type=checkbox],
input[type=radio] {
    vertical-align: middle;
    position: relative;
    bottom: 1px;
}
.mapsearch-menu li:hover {
    background: #eee;
    cursor: pointer;
}
.mapsearch-menu .button {
    display: inline-block;
    user-select: none;
    cursor: pointer;
    height: 16px;
    width: 16px;
    background-image: url("data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAABAAAAAQCAYAAAAf8/9hAAAAJ0lEQVQ4y2NgGDbgJBD/JxGfQDbgOBkGHB1mYXBi6IfBmdEwIB8AAEQSURX+8q0jAAAAAElFTkSuQmCC");
}
.mapsearch-menu {
    display: inline-block;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    margin-top: 12px;
    padding-right: 5px;
}
```

Before click:

[image]

---

After click:

[image]

I want the hamburger menu icon to stay stationary and have the dropdown menu either breakout of the parent divs bounds  or have the list items right justified.

I have been working on this for an hour and I am not getting anywhere. I tried various things (floating, etc).

ps: I prefer to have the search icon, the search text, and the hamburger all left-floated instead of the hack I am currently doing with padding with the search. If that is easier to fix that first then please attempt (I also been trying to fix that)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I updated your css below, It will probably work for you.

```
.mapsearch-menu ul {
    display: none;
    position: absolute; /* Add this you can change it as per you need */
    top: -34px; /* Add this */
    right:0px; /* Add this you can change it as per you need */
    min-width:170px; /* Add this */
    padding: 55px 0 0 0;
    margin: 0;
    user-select: none;
}

.mapsearch-menu .button {
    display: inline-block;
    user-select: none;
    cursor: pointer;
    position:relative; /* Add this */
    height: 16px;
    width: 16px;
    background-image: url("data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAABAAAAAQCAYAAAAf8/9hAAAAJ0lEQVQ4y2NgGDbgJBD/JxGfQDbgOBkGHB1mYXBi6IfBmdEwIB8AAEQSURX+8q0jAAAAAElFTkSuQmCC");
}

.mapsearch-menu li {
    background: white;
    padding: 4px;
    list-style: none;
    border: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.298039);
    margin-top: -1px;
    display:inline-block; /* Add this */
}
```